# How to filter records that contains all the words specified in a Column database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, sqlite-net

I know how to use the `LIKE` operator and `WHERE` clause to search for a specified pattern in a column of a database. e.g. `"SELECT * From customer WHERE nam like '%" & txts & "%'"`.
if the `txts` contains "The boy". It displays records with "The boy is good", "what's wrong with the boy", etc.
However, what I want is that if the `txts` contains "the boy", it should also display records like "the girl and two boys are there", "the manager came with a boy".
What syntax/code can I used to achieve this?

Comment: What you want is called full text search. Read all of this: https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html. (And try out https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/)

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm not a SQLite user but I didn't know it supported full text search. It impresses me more and more.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It depends on the library version. Full text capabilities are built-in as of SQLite version 3.9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was how I worked it out

```
Dim search = "the boy"
   Using sqlconn As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
                Dim readN As String = "SELECT id From customer WHERE 1=1 "
                Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(readN, sqlconn)
                Dim terms = search.Split()
                For i = 0 To UBound(terms)
                    Dim term = terms(i)
                    cmd.CommandText &= $" AND name LIKE :n{i}"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":n" & i, "%" & term & "%")
                Next i
                sqlconn.Open()
                Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                        MsgBox(reader.GetValue(i))
                    Next
                End While
                sqlconn.Close()
            End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, what I want is that if the txts contains "the boy", it should also display records like "the girl and two boys are there", "the manager came with a boy". What syntax/code can I used to achieve this?

Something like:

```
Dim search = "the boy"
search = "%" & search.Replace(" ", "%") & "%"

Dim sqlDa = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * From customer WHERE nam like :n", "your connection string here")
sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("n", SQLiteType.Text, search.Length, search)

Dim dt as New DataTable
sqlDa.Fill(dt)
```

The crucial part is modifying the search term from `"the boy"` to `"%the%boy%"`, but I've also included an example of how to use parameterized queries. Always (always always) use parameterized queries. There is never (ever ever) a reason not to use them.

[SQL Injection guide](http://bobby-tables.com)

[SQL Injection consequences](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+sql+injection)

---

Now that we've clarified the problem, you can either proceed with a modification of this technique:

```
Dim search = "the boy"

Dim sqlDa = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * From customer WHERE 1=1 ", "your connection string here")

Dim terms = search.Split()

For i = 0 to UBound(terms)
  Dim term = terms(i)

  sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandText &= $" AND name LIKE :n{i}"
  sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("n" & i, SQLiteType.Text, term.Length + 2, "%" & term & "%")

Next i


Dim dt as New DataTable
sqlDa.Fill(dt)
```

It just builds an SQL like:

```
SELECT * From customer WHERE 1=1 AND nam LIKE :n0 AND nam LIKE :n1
'n0 = %the%
'n1 = %boy%
```

---

Or we could use full text search; it's a bit more of a pain to set up and keep up to date (take a look at something like https://hackernoon.com/sqlite-the-unknown-feature-edfa73a6f022) - you basically create an FTS5 virtual table that tracks your real table nam/id and keep it up to date with triggers, then you could query it like:

```
Dim search = "the boy"

Dim sqlDa = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * From customer JOIN fts_customer ON customer.id = fts_customer.id WHERE fts_customer.nam MATCH :s"
sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("s", SQLiteType.Text, search.Length, search)

Dim dt as New DataTable
sqlDa.Fill(dt)
```

Note that System.Data.Sqlite doesn't seem to have FTS enabled by default (you may get a "no such module: fts5" error) - Microsoft.Data.Sqlite does, but it doesn't have a a DataAdapter (so you might ahve to switch to a `DataTable.Load(sqliteCommand.ExecuteReader())` way of working

Comment: I tried it using `SELECT * From customer WHERE 1=1 AND nam LIKE :n0 AND nam LIKE :n1`
`'n0 = %the%`
`'n1 = %boy%` and it worked. However, parameterising it as suggested is giving me problem. Inserting your code gives error `SQLiteType.Text`

Comment: Maybe cos there's a small typo on `nam` -> `name` ? It's the same code you said worked before, it just repeats itself once per parameter. Look at the SelectComamnd.CommandText and see what it actually looks like. Post the exact error message